# "... the day you find out why."

Tags: parts-of-speech, aphorism

The [Apocryphal Twain](https://marktwainstudies.com/the-apocryphal-twain-the-two-most-important-days-of-your-life/) suggests that the oft-quoted aphorism :

> The two most important days of your life are the day you were born and the day you find out why.

is not, actually, attributable to Mark Twain, though, indeed, it does sound very much like many other of his pithy sayings. The true source of the saying is not my question, however. I am interested in what I think to be the clever design of it.

One could say that 'you were born' is in elipsis and that the statement 'the day you find out why' depends on the notional understanding of the words not present.

> The two most important days of your life are the day you were born and the day you find out why *you were born.*

But the whole of the saying strikes deeper than that, I would say.

'... the day you find out why' is  not just about finding out why I, in particular, was born, It is about finding out why anyone is born. It is about finding out why anything happens.

It is about finding out why.

That is to say, it is about the whole of why.

As children can ask, why such-and-such. And then they pick up on the answer and ask 'Why so-and-so'. And why the next ... and the next.

*They want to know the whole of why.*

So my question is - what part of speech is 'why' when it means the whole of why ?

> The day I found out why.

When the word 'why' means '*the reason that everything is the way it is*' ... then what part of speech is it ?

Comment: Why?  (Why do you want to know?)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The two most important days of your life are the day you were born and the day you find out why.

This should be understood as

The two most important days of your life are {the day [that] you were born} and {the day [that] you find out why [you were born]}.

You ask

> When the word 'why' means 'the reason that everything is the way it is' ... then what part of speech is it?

but this has a problem: it never means that. The following will demonstrate that the nearest it could mean (but does not) is "...the day you find out the answer **to the why/the enigma of birth**."

Why is either

1. an adverb = for what reason:

1883   D. C. Murray Hearts ix   *Why don't you learn Italian?*

Or

2. an interjection

1893   M. Pemberton Iron Pirate i   *Mary looked up suddenly..and said,..‘Why, I believe I've been asleep!’*

Or

3. a noun = reason:

1832   R. Southey Ess. II. 415   *The reader who may not be..acquainted with the when, and the how, and the why of the surrender.*

or

4. (OED) A question beginning with (or consisting of) the word ‘why?’; a question as to the reason of something; hence, a problem, an enigma.

1866   A. Steinmetz Weathercasts 20   *She could supply the ready ‘because’ to many of the old philosopher's ‘whys’.*

I can find no example of the noun “why” appearing in the singular without a determiner, and this indicates that the noun "why" is countable. **Your example has no determiner**: it appears to be an adverb.

If it did mean “**the question of** why we were born” or “**the question of** why anyone is born, then it would be a noun and it would be

The two most important days of your life are {the day [that] you were born} and the day [that] you find out **the why**.

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks for the offer. People do vote things down and often fail to give a reason or an alternative. This means that neither of us will learn, which is unfortunate. I have reread your question and my answer. I can see nothing wrong with either. If there is a better answer, then when it appears, I will remove mine.

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with either your answer or Nigel's question. Pay no heed to those who down-vote.